# Weird behavior of clearInterval()

Tags: javascript, timer, addeventlistener

So I am trying to code a timer using JavaScript. Everything is fine when the page is loaded, the only thing is that when I reset the timer multiple times or change its duration with the apply button (please refer to the code to see those buttons) instead of behaving as expected, the old instances of the timer keep running. I suspect that it has to do with eventListeners. Any ideas?

**HTML Code:**

```
<body>

        <h1 class="page-header text-center">title</h1>

           <div class="container text-center">  

                <div class="row">   

                  <div id="customizeLength">
                      <p>Customize timer:</p>
                      <button id="plus" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                      <span id="sessLength"></span>
                      <button id="minus" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
                      <button id="apply"type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">> Apply</button>   
                  </div>    

                    <br/>

                 <div id="clock">
                 <span id="minutes"></span> : <span id="seconds"></span>
                 </div>

                    <br/>

                <button id="reset" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                  > Reset 
                </button>

              <div>

          <div>

        <script src=./script.js></script>   

</body>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
//Countdown from provided later time to current time:
function getTimeRemaining(endTime) {

    var t = Date.parse(endTime) - Date.parse(new Date());
    var seconds = Math.floor((t/1000) % 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor((t/1000/60) % 60);

    return {
        "tracker": t,
        "seconds": seconds,
        "minutes": minutes,
    }

  }

//Update html elements:
function updateClock(endTime){

  var t = getTimeRemaining(endTime);
  var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
        var minutes = clock.querySelector("#minutes");
        var seconds = clock.querySelector("#seconds");

            minutes.innerHTML = t.minutes;
            seconds.innerHTML = t.seconds; 

  if (t.tracker === 0){
    clearInterval(timerID);
  }

}

//Modify Date's prototype to append function addMinutes():
Date.prototype.addMinutes = function(minutes=30){

        this.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() + minutes);
        return this;
};

//###################################################################################

var param_ = new Date().addMinutes();
updateClock(param_);
var timerID = setInterval(updateClock,1000, param_);

var sessLength = document.getElementById("sessLength");
    sessLength.innerHTML = "30";

var buttonReset = document.getElementById("reset");
var applySession = document.getElementById("apply");

buttonReset.addEventListener("click", function(){

        clearInterval(timerID);
        var param_ = new Date().addMinutes();
        updateClock(param_);
        setInterval(updateClock,1000, param_);
});

//Customize Session's Length:
var addMinutes_ = document.getElementById("plus");
var reduceMinutes_ = document.getElementById("minus");

addMinutes_.addEventListener("click", function(){

        var sessLength_plus1 = parseInt(sessLength.textContent) + 1;
        sessLength.innerHTML = sessLength_plus1;
});

reduceMinutes_.addEventListener("click", function(){

    var sessLength_minus1 = parseInt(sessLength.textContent) - 1;     
    sessLength_minus1 < 0 ? sessLength.innerHTML = 0 : sessLength.innerHTML = sessLength_minus1;

});

applySession.addEventListener("click", function(){

            var apply_ = sessLength.textContent;
            clearInterval(timerID);
            var param_ = new Date().addMinutes(parseInt(apply_));
            updateClock(param_);
            setInterval(updateClock,1000, param_);

});
```

Many thanks for your patience.

Comment: In `clearInterval(timeinterval);` - who is `timeinterval`? in the posted code I cannot find any reference with that name.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Ovidiu, it refers to timerID, I'll edit that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the interval a second time after having cleared it, you must still assign the returned ID to the the *timerID* variable, because in general it will be a different ID

So change:

```
setInterval(updateClock,1000, param_);
```

to

```
timerID = setInterval(updateClock,1000, param_);
```

wherever you call `setInterval`.

Also note you reference an undefined variable *timeinterval*. Probably you intended *timerID* to occur there?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @trincot, I replaced that variable with timerID, though it has no incidence on the issue. I used your snippet but unfortunately I still get the same error

Comment: I don't get any error, and it seems to work fine. Are you sure you corrected *all* occurrences? See this working snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/07q043gm/

Comment: I used the var keyword like this: var timerID = setInterval(updateClock,1000, param_); I removed it and now everything is fine, many thanks again :)

Comment: Ah, yes, if you use `var` within a function, you create another variable, different from the global *timerID* which thus remains unchanged.